# converting vb to c# (Type and identifier are both required in a foreach statement )

Tags: c#

vb code:

```
Dim janTbl As Janus.Windows.GridEX.GridEXTable

For Each janTbl In lvtoolpartsinfo.Tables`
```

c# code:

```
Janus.Windows.GridEX.GridEXTable janTbl = new Janus.Windows.GridEX.GridEXTable();

foreach (janTbl in lvtoolpartsinfo.Tables)
{    }
```

error :Type and identifier are both required in a foreach statement

**edited:**

c# code:

```
foreach (Janus.Windows.GridEX.GridEXTable janTbl in lvtoolpartsinfo.Tables)
    janTbl.Columns[0].Visible = false;
    janTbl.Columns[1].Caption = "Part Number";
    janTbl.Columns[1].ShowRowSelector = true;
    janTbl.Columns[1].EditType = Janus.Windows.GridEX.EditType.NoEdit;
    janTbl.Columns[1].Width = 120;
```

error:

```
line 3:The name 'janTbl' does not exist in the current context
line 4 ...
line 5..
```

Comment: @sstan the error occur in line2 . in c# code

Comment: You don't have the braces `{` and `}`.  Without them, only the first line `janTbl.Columns[0].Visible = false;` is considered part of the loop.  The others will be ***outside***, so it's normal that they can't see `janTbl`.  Look at my answer again. Notice where the braces are placed.

Answer (score 1):

Delete this line:

```
Janus.Windows.GridEX.GridEXTable janTbl = new Janus.Windows.GridEX.GridEXTable();
```

And then you simply need to fix your `foreach` statement to include the type for `janTbl` and you are set:

```
foreach (Janus.Windows.GridEX.GridEXTable janTbl in lvtoolpartsinfo.Tables) 
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: it cannot recognize the janTbl inside the codition{}

Comment: The name 'janTbl' does not exist in the current context

Comment: I'm not clear on which line is giving you the error.  I don't see how the `foreach` statement would give you that error.  Why don't you edit your post to include all the relevant code, and specify which exact line is giving you the error.

Comment: this is my code :  foreach (Janus.Windows.GridEX.GridEXTable janTbl in lvtoolpartsinfo.Tables)
            
            {
            janTbl.Columns[0].Visible = false;
            janTbl.Columns[1].Caption = "Part Number";
            janTbl.Columns[1].ShowRowSelector = true;
            janTbl.Columns[1].Width = 120;

Comment: It's hard to read the code in a comment.  Please edit your original post, and put the code there.  And please specify which line is giving you the error.  Chances are that you didn't put the `{}` in the right place, and so you have a dangling `janTbl` reference ***outside*** the `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing braces:

```
foreach (var janTbl in lvtoolpartsinfo.Tables)
{ // <--- don't forget this

    janTbl.Columns[0].Visible = false;
    janTbl.Columns[1].Caption = "Part Number";
    janTbl.Columns[1].ShowRowSelector = true;
    janTbl.Columns[1].EditType = Janus.Windows.GridEX.EditType.NoEdit;
    janTbl.Columns[1].Width = 120;

} // <--- and this
```

Without the braces, only the first line after the `foreach()` statement is part of the loop. Code after that is outside of the loop, and it's the same as if you had written this:

```
foreach (Janus.Windows.GridEX.GridEXTable janTbl in lvtoolpartsinfo.Tables)
        janTbl.Columns[0].Visible = false;

janTbl.Columns[1].Caption = "Part Number";
janTbl.Columns[1].ShowRowSelector = true;
janTbl.Columns[1].EditType = Janus.Windows.GridEX.EditType.NoEdit;
janTbl.Columns[1].Width = 120;
```